# How to fix deprecation warning for using non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

Please forgive my noob-ish question, but I am a little confused as to why this warning occurs and what I can do to remedy it.

I tried replacing `df['Air Temp']` with `df[tuple('Air Temp')]` but it only raised more errors.

CODE:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("./data/elnino.csv")

df.columns = [col.strip() for col in df.columns]

df['Air Temp'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Air Temp'], errors = 'coerce')
df['Sea Surface Temp'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Sea Surface Temp'], 
errors = 'coerce')
```

ERROR:

> stats.py:1713: FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for 
>       multidimensional indexing is deprecated; use `arr[tuple(seq)]` 
>       instead of `arr[seq]`. In the future this will be interpreted as an 
>       array index, `arr[np.array(seq)]`, which will result either in an 
>       error or a different result.
>       return np.add.reduce(sorted[indexer] * weights, axis=axis) / sumval

Comment: Are you sure to use tuple? Please look at this output:
 tuple('Air Temp')
Out[42]: ('A', 'i', 'r', ' ', 'T', 'e', 'm', 'p'

Comment: [Some googling](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/b7a1ebc67eda08f230ac88af0acb224c383a6654/scipy/stats/stats.py#L1740) suggests that you're using `scipy.stats` at some point. Please can you show the code that's doing that?

Comment: And it looks as though it's a minor bug in SciPy, fixed [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/8944/commits/1955c60c08337c6d2bafcd2c2a94cc44feac8ecc). So you can basically ignore it: when you update to the next version of SciPy (when it becomes available), the warning should go away.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, doing this solved it for me:
In command line run the following:

```
pip install --upgrade scipy
```